# How to get a debug output from the find command?

Tags: scripting, find, debug

I have the following find command:

```
find /home/  -type d -name "something"
```

what I want to achieve is to know which directory/file is checked by the find command no matter the fact that it does or does not match the name I have set.

Basically I want to see every action that the find command will perform once I launch the above piece of code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an

```
lsof -p `pidof find`
```

you can see, where is your find command currently.

With a

```
strace -p `pidof find`
```

you can check, what it is doing currently.

None of them have really beautiful output - they are debug tools, but the little bit of learning their output is also really useful.

Comment: Thank you! I actually found similar solution myself searching over the web. 

It seems that the find command does not actually have a log option for example or an option where similar output to the strace command can be provided. 

Thank you once again and have a great day!

Answer (score 3):

The man file for find has debug options

you probably want `find -D search -type d -name "something" 2>&1`

it doesn't seem to be in the man file but `find -D help`

prints

search     Navigate the directory tree verbosely

Answer (score 0):

*Although the above two commands do actually answer the question I would like to present a less verbose output which satisfies the part:*

> to know which directory/file is checked by the find command no matter
> the fact that it does or does not match the name I have set.

`find /home/` **`-print`** `-type d -name "something"`

### Using the `-print` expression.

As stated in the manual:

- If no expression is given, the expression -print is used by default *as if it were put at the end of the command*

  - `find /home/ -type d -name "something"`

    - as if it were --> `find /home/ -type d -name "something" -print`

but if you place the print expression at the beginning as follows

- `find /home/` **`-print`** `-type d -name "something"`

  - It will print out every *file* that is being checked

    - *of course the matched file will also be printed as it forms part of the checked files, but you do not have a way of knowing which one it was*

If you place the print expression at the beginning **and** end:

- `find /home/` **`-print`**`-type d -name "something"`**`-print`**

  - It will print out every *file* that is being checked
  - It will print out every *matched file* aswell

So now the ones that matched will appear twice. Although a bit difficult to see if there are a lot of files.

So using the expression `printf` instead of `print` you can use
[ANSI excape color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) within the format of the printf command, **but** as explainted in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/520310/43437) the `-printf` flag of find is different from the usual built-in from bash and "the color code sequence and the `%p` needs to be in the same argument". This can lead to the following expression:

```
find /home/ -print -type d -name "something" -printf '\033[;34m%p\033[0m\n'
```

*This will print the matches out in blue*

more info available in [the find man docs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)